# how to import cck data from drupal6 to drupal7?

Tags: nodes, importing-exporting

Now I have to upgrade to drupal7 website from drupal6, but there has been a new during the upgrade of the old site data, mainly CCK and taxonomy, what would I do for the way to the input of CCK in 6 to 7?
How can I do this?

Comment: There has a been a new what?

Comment: Simple point said, is how to 6 data import to 7

Comment: Please correct the missing word at "there has been a new ... during".

Comment: It is from drupal6 upgrading to drupal7 a web site

Comment: Yes, I understand. What I mean that you seem to have one or more words missing in your question between "but there has been a new" and "during the upgrade" ;).

Comment: I'm just asking to see if your question is about anything else than what can be found in Drupal.org for example on https://drupal.org/node/570162. Number 15 talks about CCK.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Migrate](https://drupal.org/project/migrate) module along with the [Drupal-to-Drupal data migration](https://drupal.org/project/migrate_d2d) module

Migrate

> The migrate module provides a flexible framework for migrating content
>   into Drupal from other sources (e.g., when converting a web site from
>   another CMS to Drupal). Out-of-the-box, support for creating core
>   Drupal objects such as nodes, users, files, terms, and comments are
>   included - it can easily be extended for migrating other kinds of
>   content. Content is imported and rolled back using a bundled web
>   interface (Migrate UI module) or included Drush commands (strongly
>   recommended).

Drupal-to-Drupal data migration

> migrate_d2d provides a framework based on the Migrate API for
>   migrating content from Drupal 5, Drupal 6, or Drupal 7 sites into the
>   Drupal 7

Another option would to use the [feeds API](https://drupal.org/project/feeds) to import data. You could create feeds of the contents in drupal 6 and use feeds API to create the required contents in Drupal 7

[Data export import](https://drupal.org/project/data_export_import) is another module that does import and export of content.

[Node export](https://drupal.org/project/node_export) this another module that can be used along with Feeds